# Fazer um loop pelas linhas de um arquivo e imprimir partes dela em sequência

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell

Tenho um arquivo de texto que está com várias linhas separadas por dois pontos. Veja como exemplo:

```
teste1:testee1
teste2:testee2
teste:testeeee
```

Utilizando um laço `for`, estou tentando fazer com que o script imprima na tela a primeira parte e logo em seguida a segunda, por exemplo assim:

```
$ teste1
$ testee1
$ teste2
$ testee2
# Assim vai indo...
```

Só que não entendi o porquê ele simplesmente está imprimindo na tela tudo antes dos dois pontos, para depois pegar a parte depois dos dois pontos. Exemplo de como está saindo:

```
$ teste1
$ teste2
$ teste
# agora começa a imprimir a parte depois dos dois pontos, o que está errado
$ testee1
$ testee2
$ testeeeee
```

Código do script:

```
for IA in "$(cat teste.txt)"; do
STR1="$(echo "$IA" | cut -d ":" -f1)" #pega a primeira palavra depois dos dois pontos.
STR2="$(echo "$IA" | cut -d ":" -f2)" #pega a segunda palavra depois dos dois pontos.

echo "$STR1"
echo "$STR2"

sleep 3
done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Primeiro vamos modificar um pouco seu loop:

```
for IA in "$(cat teste.txt)"; do
  echo "- $IA"
done
```

Ou seja, antes de cada linha, estou imprimindo também um hífen. A saída é:

```
- teste1:testee1
teste2:testee2
teste:testeeee
```

Ou seja, todo o conteúdo foi considerado uma "linha" só.

---

Esse problema é explicado em mais detalhes [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17099860), e uma solução seria fazer algo como:

```
while read LINE
do
...
done < file.txt
```

Mas se a última linha do arquivo não tiver uma quebra de linha, ela será ignorada, então a maneira mais garantida (retirado [daqui](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/482517)) é:

```
while IFS= read -r IA || [ -n "$IA" ]
do
  STR1="$(echo "$IA" | cut -d ":" -f1)" 
  STR2="$(echo "$IA" | cut -d ":" -f2)"
  
  echo "$STR1"
  echo "$STR2"

  sleep 3
done < teste.txt
```

Com isso a saída será:

```
teste1
testee1
teste2
testee2
teste
testeeee
```